# Jquery Logout Confirmation on button click in php

Tags: jquery, button

I am trying to make a jQuery logout confirmation alert box  with a Html button click in php. 
But it's not working

Jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("logout").submit(function(){
            if(confirm("Are you sure want to exit ?")){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" name="logout" id="logout"  value="Log Out" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to update your jQuery selector.

> $("logout").submit(function(){

It should be `$("#logout")` since you're trying to get the element by ID. Just like in CSS, you need to include the hashtag when you want to select an element by it's id.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logout').on('click', function(e){
            if(confirm("Are you sure you want to logout?"))
                window.location.href = "http://localhost/login.php";

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ccubu27n/).

Comment: Thats ok ! but now i want that as i click ok the login.php page loads and if i click on cancel it remains in current page .tell me where i insert the code `header("location:login.php");`<br>

Comment: Is your input in a form?

Comment: yes .i am trying to make an admin page in php ,as admin clicks on logout button it should confirm logout ,if yes then load the login.php page otherwise remain in same page

Comment: Well after your form submits, simply redirect the user to login.php

Comment: i have two buttons in the form ,first one is change the password when i click on it it redirects the page to changepass.php file .But as i click on logout button it shows confirmation massage but not redirecting to login.php page

Comment: my file is in htdocs folder on localhost sever which url should i use to redirect to login.php

Comment: You can use `window.location.origin + "/login.php";` as the url

Comment: i tried it so many ways but it's not redirecting to login.php page

Comment: i tried this but not working                                    'window.location="http://localhost/login.php";'

Comment: How do you access your login.php normally?

Comment: header("location:adminpage.php");     but its working  is in php

Comment: i want to make a logout confirmation box and redirect the page from jquery

Comment: Then do `localhost/adminpage.php`

Comment: i am already standing in adminpage.php .I want to redirect the page to login.php after confirmation

Comment: when i insert the addres http://localhost/login.php in address bar its opens the file

Comment: but not opening after confirmation mesage

Comment: Alright try the one I just changed. It's working fine for me. I changed the window.location to `window.location.href` and it's always returning false.

Comment: Thanks dear thank you very much for solving my problem

Comment: No problem! Have a nice day.